# Some questions on the famous Gidas-Ni-Nirenberg 1979 paper

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

So, I'm reading the classical paper

- Gidas, B., Ni, WM. & Nirenberg, L., *Symmetry and Related Properties via the Maximum Principle*, Commun. Math. Phys. **68** (1979) pp. 209–243, doi:[10.1007/BF01221125](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01221125), [Project Euclid](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-68/issue-3/Symmetry-and-related-properties-via-the-maximum-principle/cmp/1103905359.full),

and I am in trouble with some passages. Since giving a complete description of the framework where the problem is posed would be unfeasible, I seek help from people familiar with the referred paper, and this is why I'm posting it here instead of posting at MathStackExchange.

**First question**

In the proof of Lemma 2.1, when the hypothesis that $f(0) \geq 0$ in $\Omega_\varepsilon$ is made, we obtain equation $\widehat{\text{(2.1)}}$:
$$
\Delta u + b_1 u_1 + f(u) - f(0) \leq 0.
$$
Then the authors claim that, by the Mean Value Theorem,
$$
\Delta u + b_1 u_1 + c(x) u \leq 0, \quad (*)
$$
for some function $c(x)$.

> How was the Mean Value Theorem used to yield $(*)$?

**Second question**

In the proof of Lemma 2.2, the authors claim that
$$
w(x) = v(x) - u(x) \leq 0, \quad w \not\equiv 0
$$
and
$$
\Delta w + b_1(x) w_1 + c(x) w \geq 0, \quad (**)
$$
by the integral form of the Mean Value Theorem. Again,

> How was the Mean Value Theorem used?

**Third question**

Again in the proof of Lemma 2.2, the authors use the Maximum Principle for the equation $(**)$

> Do we know if c(x) is negative in order to apply the Maximum Principle? Is there a reference for a Maximum Principle where $c$ is anything (which is what they use, as I understand)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first question: you just need that given a solution $u$ there exists a function $c(x)$ such that $f(u(x)) - f(0) = c(x) u(x)$. This is possible because by the Mean Value Theorem applied to $f$ there exists a function $v(x)$ between $u(x)$ and $0$ such that $f(u(x)) - f(0) = f'(v(x)) u(x)$.

For your second question, the MVT is applied to get $f(v(x)) - f(u(x)) = f'(z(x)) (v(x) - u(x))$ for some $z(x)$ between $v(x)$ and $u(x)$.

For your third question, the authors explain exactly this point on page 212 of the paper, in section 1.3. As they explained, the case $c(x) \leq 0$ is well-known, but the proof *for the specific statement that they need* also works for general-signed $c(x)$. They included a proof of the statement, which spans the bottom lines of page 212 and the top half of page 213.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had indeed take a glimpse at pages 212 and 213, but I thought the proof was just for Hopf's Lemma. One last issue: why do they mention the "integral" form of the Mean Value Theorem, in the second time they use it?

Comment: @DaniloGregorinAfonso: you are right, the proof they included is only for the Hopf Mx. Principle. But they also include a reference to [7] which contains the proof of the statement that they need. Note that their specific maximum principle only deals with the case of $u \leq 0$ with the maximum point at $u = 0$, which is probably what makes it work. (It's been a while since I looked at this paper.) // I have no idea why they specified the integral form of the MVT, since $f$ is $C^1$.

Comment: Actually, if you let $u = e^{\lambda\cdot x} v(x)$. Then $$ 0 \leq Lu =e^{\lambda\cdot x}( a \cdot \partial^2 v + b \cdot \partial v + 2a(\lambda)\cdot \partial v ) + e^{\lambda \cdot x} ( c + a(\lambda,\lambda) + b \cdot \lambda) v $$ For large $\lambda$, the final term is "positive" times $v$, which is non-positive, and hence $v$ is a non-positive function with $L' v \geq 0$ where $L'$ has no zero-order term, and so you can apply the standard strong maximum principle.